# Как сделать рассылку пользователям бота в телеграмм PHP

Tags: php, telegram-bot, бот, telegram

Есть бот, при авторизации он сохраняет юзер айди человека в базу, как реализовать рассылку по пользователям бота?

Comment: Создаёте экземпляр класса бота. У бота должен быть метод `send_message`, где в качестве аргумента можно передать `chat_id`, текст сообщения, клавиатуру и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

У телеграмма имеется api-метод:

```
               $response = (HttpClient::create())->request(
                    'POST',
                    sprintf(
                        '%s/bot%s/%s',
                        'https://api.telegram.org',
                        ***ваш токен от бота***,
                        'sendMessage'
                    ),
                    [
                        'query' => [
                           'chat_id' => ***чат в который отправляем***, 
                           'text' => ***сообщение***
                         ],
                    ]
                );

                if ($response->getStatusCode() === Response::HTTP_OK) {
                    $response = $response->toArray();

                    if (isset($response['ok']) && $response['ok']) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
```

Далее берем выборку из базы, перебираем каждого юзера и юзаем данный метод для отправки в сообщения.